# I might delete my mcpe because it keeps on crashing on 1.1.0. when I delete it then re download it, do I need to pay for it again or no?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Im going to delete my minecraft pe because it keeps on lagging then crashing me out of the game.. When I'm going to re download it, will it ask me to pay for it again or is it an Pay once then play forever app?

Answer (score 1):

The purchase of Minecraft: Pocket Edition is *linked to your phone's account* , be it Android, Apple, or some other form of operating system. As long as you are logged in to the original account that you used to buy the game with, **you should be able to re-download it without having to pay again.**

Comment: As a confirmation of sorts: I bought MCPE for one Android tablet which then broke. I bought another Android tablet, but put off reinstalled MCPE. After a couple months, I reinstalled  I did not have to pay again, and it works fine.